# Exception to ComboBox

Tags: c#, list, combobox, drive

I am looking for a way to remove the physical disk 0 when the aquisition of the list of device on the computer.

the command executed is as follows:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
        foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisks.Get())
        {
            driveList.Items.Add(moDisk["Model"].ToString());
        }
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: how to remove the physical disk 0 paid in the list.

Comment: You need to put in more efforts for the question to make sense, *physical disk 0* where does that figure out here and do you mean to remove something from the `driveList` (Whatz that anyway)

Comment: get a screwdriver, take off the case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
    foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisks.Get())
    {
        if(!moDisk["DeviceId"].ToString().Contains("PHYSICALDRIVE0"))
        {
            driveList.Items.Add(moDisk["Model"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Or more simply, change your WQL to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE NOT NAME LIKE '%PHYSICALDRIVE0'
```

Answer (score 0):

How is it that you can reliably recognise physical disk drive 0?

If you comment out the adding to the drive list combobox and instead add in the code fragment below you can see the properties of the ManagementObject and decide which to use:

```
foreach(var prop in moDisk.Properties)  
{  
  Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value);  
}
```

For example (I haven't got enough drives to be certain) you may want to exclude Index 0 which you can either do by checking within the loop and not adding to the combobox or by updating your select:

```
select * from Win32_DiskDrive where Index <> 0
```

Also you can just select Model rather than *